# compare between stored database rows and exact post

Tags: php

I'm going to store some words inside db `my_table (id,word)` as follow

[image: my_table]

Now i've input post

```
$comment = $_POST[comment]; // "blab blah shit blah" have banned word (shit)
```

i want to do the following
if the comment contains any of the stored words inside `my_table` then it gives `echo "banned"; exit;` and if not then go on `echo "passed";`

how then to compare it ?

is this could be right

```
SELECT 1
FROM my_table
WHERE $comment LIKE CONCAT('%', my_table.word , '%')
LIMIT 1
```

then if gives results then echo `"banned";` and if not then `echo "passed"`; !

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel i'm getting some manual comment posts advertise for some kind of medicine whatever so i'll store some words to ban it then if someone post comment with any of such medicines names i've stored then it will stop it before submit to database ~ thanks and this will helps me a lot to stop some real real bad spammers

Comment: What a *code* have you got so far? Do you have you a code to fetch these words from database?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: "code" in this context is an uncountable noun; thus, "a code" is incorrect.

Comment: Related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem

Comment: @Lightness thanks. My feeling for the foreign language failed me.

Comment: why i'm getting -ve feedback :) am i said something wrong !

Comment: @JackBen: Please take more care over your question. It only takes a moment to write capital letters and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just quickly wrote this. Not really tested but it can give you an idea on how to go about yours in a more optimized way.

```
//database connection done here
$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$comment = $_POST[comment]; 
$commentArray = explode(" ", $comment);
$counter = count($commentArray);
$check = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        for($i==0; $i<$counter;$i++)
        {
            if(strcasecmp($commentArray[$i],$row['word'])==0) {
                $check = 1;
            }
        }   
    }
if($check == 1)
 {
    echo "banned"; exit;
} else echo "passed";
```

Comment: ~ thanks for the idea but it gives error Fatal error: Function name must be a string in this line $counter = $count($commentArray);

Comment: Sorry I just removed the $ sign before the count. You should have figured that out

Comment: It works perfect than ever i imagined thanks a lot , that would save almost my website from a lot of certain spam posts that do advertise or banned medicine.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 1
FROM table
WHERE user_input_text LIKE CONCAT('%', table.word, '%')
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: thanks but can you please correct me if something wrong suppose the input text is $comment and my table with words i've stored before is my_table then upon your idea :

SELECT 1
FROM my_table
WHERE $comment LIKE CONCAT('%', my_table.word , '%')
LIMIT 1

then if gives results then echo banned and if not then echo passed to whatever ! right

Comment: Right. But do not send $comment pure to you database, use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql_num_rows() to check to see if it exists or not. Also, do not forget to escape your inputs!

```
$comment = mysql_real_escape($_POST['comment']);
```

Comment: ~ [Use mysql_num_rows() to check to see if it exists or not] the question is all about how to do exactly like you've said :)